# Move shape to 4 directions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on my jQuery skills and want to create a simple shape, and 4 buttons beneath it that will control it and move up, down, left or right once the user clicks it. What is the easiest way to do that?

The problem is that the shape is moving in a very strange direction.
This is what I wrote:

JS:

```
$("#rightButton").click(function(){
        $("#shape").animate({
        right: "+=50px"
        });
    });
  $("#leftButton").click(function(){
        $("#shape").animate({
        left: "-=50px"
        });
    });
  $("#upButton").click(function(){
        $("#shape").animate({
        top: "+=50px"
        });
    });
  $("#downButton").click(function(){
        $("#shape").animate({
        bottom: "-=50px"
        });
    });
```

Comment: welcome @SuppoGirl :-)

can you share some code? what have you tried? are you trying to make the element move a certain distance from the origin point? or can you click the `up` button twice and the element will go up twice the amount?

Comment: I'd suggest using CSS transitions instead of jQuery's animate()

Answer (score 1):

This is something extremely basic I knocked up in 5 minutes, but perhaps it would give you a starting point?

https://jsfiddle.net/srbqLgx8/1/

```js
    $('a').on('click',function(e){
     var $shape = $('#shape'),
       dir = $(this).data('dir');
        if( dir == 'left' ){
         $shape.animate({left: '-=10px'}, 100);
        }else if( dir == 'right' ){
         $shape.animate({left: '+=10px'}, 100);
        }else if( dir == 'up' ){
         $shape.animate({top: '-=10px'}, 100);
        }else if( dir == 'down' ){
         $shape.animate({top: '+=10px'}, 100);
        }
     e.preventDefault();
    });
```

```css
    #shape{
      border-radius:50%;
      width:50px;
      height:50px;
      background-color:red;
      position:relative;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-dir="up">UP</a> | 
    <a href="#" data-dir="down">DOWN</a> | 
    <a href="#" data-dir="left">LEFT</a> |
    <a href="#" data-dir="right">RIGHT</a>
    <div id="shape"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the amazing answer. It was a great starting point. Could you please clarify why do you use  e.preventDefault();? Is it really necessary?

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` prevents the default action of the anchor (`<a/>`) tags from firing. In this case, the default action would just be to add a hashtag to the end of the URL, so it's not a big deal if you wanted to lose that line.